# min value is not equal to blank in pivot pandas

Tags: pandas, pivot, min

My input data is like

DocumentID          InvoiceDate
25001                      01-02-2020
25001
25001                      10-02-2020
25001                      25-02-2020
25001
25001                      28-02-202
26001                      10-04-2020
26001                      21-05-2020
26001
27001                      09-07-2020       ​

So i want minimum and maximum  date.

I am able to get maximum value with the same code but not be able to get minimum value becouse of blank data

this is my code

Min_Date = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['InvoiceDate'], index=['DocumentID'], aggfunc={'InvoiceDate': np.min},).reset_index()

this is my output
min value come as none

```
0        
1        
2        
3        
4        
       ..
1844     
1845     
1846     
1847     
1848     
Name: Invoice Date, Length: 1849, d type: object

this is my output
min value come as none
```

Comment: what is the input data? what is the question?

Comment: You might need to fill blanks with 0 as blank is not a number Min_table.fillna(0, inplace=True)

Comment: I want alteast minimum date , not blank and not 0